# AttrbuteError while using serializer in djangorestframework

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-rest-framework

I get 'AttrbuteError: 'DeferredAttribute'  has no attribute 'isoformat'' when i try to serialize the django model using the djangorestframework
Below is the model that im trying to serialize

```
class PrimaryRecord(models.Model):
      primaryId = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
      primary_track = models.CharField(max_length=30)
      title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
      start_date = models.DateField()
      create_date = models.DateField()
      year = models.IntegerField()
```

and the serializer class that i'm using is below

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from snippets.models import Assesor, PrimaryRecord, PrimaryAssesor

class PrimaryRecordSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
      primary_track = serializers.CharField(max_length=30)
      title = serializers.CharField(max_length=255)
      start_date = serializers.DateField(format = None)
      create_date = serializers.DateField(format = None)
      year = serializers.IntegerField()

  def create(self, validated_data):
      return PrimaryAssesor.objects.create(**validated_data)

  def update(self, instance, validated_data):
      instance.primary_track = validated_data.get('primary_track', instance.primary_track)
      instance.title = validated_data.get('title', instance.title)
      instance.start_date = validated_data.get('start_date', instance.start_date)
      instance.create_date = validated_data.get('create_date', instance.create_date)
      instance.year = validated_data.get('year', instance.year)
      instance.save()
      return instance
```

Im following  [this](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/1-serialization/) tutorial for learning djangorestframework.

I do the following steps

```
p1 = PrimaryRecord(primary_track='P2017-98',title='ABC',start_date=date(2017,6,23),create_date=timezone().now(),year=2017)
p1.save()
serializer = PrimaryRecordSerializer(primaryrecord)
serializer.data # the error occurs here

 'AttrbuteError: 'DeferredAttribute' has no attribute 'isoformat''
```

Comment: What's `primaryrecord` in your code sample ? It's not defined.

Comment: @Linovia thanks.... this question of yours solved my problem

Comment: Glad you fixed it :)

Answer (score 0):

You are using wrong variable `primaryrecord` instead of `p1` when you are initializing `PrimaryRecordSerializer` serializer. It should be,

```
serializer = PrimaryRecordSerializer(p1)
```

not

```
serializer = PrimaryRecordSerializer(primaryrecord)
```